# Storing std::vectors in google::dense_hash_map makes it slower

Tags: c++, hashtable, std

I need mapping from `uint64`->[list of `uint64`] (list length is constant per hash table).

I have tried using `google::dense_hash_map` in two ways:

1.`google::dense_hash_map<uint64, std::array<uint64, 10>, Hash64> //10 for example`

2.`google::dense_hash_map<uint64, std::vector<uint64>, Hash64>`

(1) works much faster (3-fold) than (2). The problem is, I don't want to define the size of array in compilation time but when defining the hash-map, is there another option possible?

Most of my operations are modifying the values in the hash-table, and I sometime erase all elements so I can use the same allocated memory.

Comment: In what way is the second option slower? How have you determined this? What are you measuring?

Comment: How does it look like in comparison with `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: The reason (1) works faster has nothing to do with `google::dense_hash_map`, but because `std::array` is a much simpler container than `std::vector`. Copying a `std::array` is a much simpler operation than copying `std::vector`, and your actual code likely does a bunch of inefficient things, like passing parameters by value, which amplifies `std::vector`'s inefficiency in that regard. Figure out where your own code's inefficiencies are, and fix them. It's not in `dense_hash_map`.

Comment: `std::vector` stores its elements in dynamically allocated buffers, which involves indirect addressing when accessing elements and can lead to more cache misses in your case. I am not familiar with `google::dense_hash_map` internals, but I would assume that with `std::array` array elements are stored in a more compact way in memory and there is less need for (slow) dynamic memory allocations.

Comment: @DanielLangr It's something like a flat hash table with linear probing, first done on a type-agnostic meta table. Lookup typically has little element access.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to employ some memory pooling to avoid dynamic allocations and get more compact (cache-friendly) memory usage. This is a very simple examplary solution that works for me together with `boost::dense_hash_map`:

```
template <typename T>
class pooled_rt_array {
   public:
      static void init_pool(size_t capacity) {
         pool_.resize(capacity);
         top_ = pool_.data();
      }

      pooled_rt_array() : data_(top_), size_(0) { }

      pooled_rt_array(size_t size) : data_(top_), size_(size) {
         assert(top_ + size <= pool_.data() + pool_.size()); // not safe, in fact
         top_ += size;
      }

      T & operator[](size_t n) { return *(data_ + n); }
      const T & operator[](size_t n) const { return *(data_ + n); }
      size_t size() const { return size_; }

   private:
      T * data_;
      size_t size_;

      static std::vector<T> pool_;
      static T * top_;
};

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> pooled_rt_array<T>::pool_;

template <typename T>
T * pooled_rt_array<T>::top_;
```

A simple usage:

```
int main() {
    using value_t = pooled_rt_array<uint64_t>;
    google::hash_dense_map<uint64_t, value_t
       /* , std::hash<uint64_t>, std::equal_to<uint64_t> */
    > m;
    m.set_empty_key(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF);

    size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;
    value_t::init_pool(1000000 * n); // pool for 1000000 arrays
    value_t a(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) a[i] = i;
    m[0] = std::move(a);
}
```

I also did some benchmark and this was much faster than storing `std::vector` in the map.

If the size of arrays is the same for all of them, you can even remove the `size_` member variable from `pooled_rt_array`, which will make its instances having the size of a single pointer.

---

Note that there are much more sophisticated ways how to employ memory pooling, such as those provided by Boost. You can for example use some special pool-aware allocators and use them with `std::vector`.